# Show Rails Contact Form on main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a contact form in Rails 4 with this **[example](http://l4u.github.io/articles/create-a-rails-4-site-with-contact-us-form/).**
But I want to display this contact form on the main/show page of my application. How can I do this?

**routes.rb.**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:error] = nil
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And easy and clean way would be to create a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

_contact_form.html.erb (Partials always starts with an underscore)

```
.container
  %h1 Contact
  = simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
    = f.input :name, :required => true
    = f.input :email, :required => true
    = f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => false, :input_html => {:rows => 10}

    .hidden
      = f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!'
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary"
```

Then, in your index page:

```
<%= render "contacts/contact_form" %>
```

and in your controller index action( I don't know if 'welcome/index' is on project's controller or contacts controller)

```
def index
 #your code
 @contact = Contact.new
end
```

Finally, you seem quite new to rails, I'd like to recommend a free [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! :)